# Where can I find a good translation with explanation for bava kamma

Tags: talmud-gemara, bava-kamma

List a lot of different places where I can find them, but not mercaveh. I need with a good explanation.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma?tab=contents

Comment: https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899067049.html

Comment: As my friend posted above, artscroll or sefaria are good picks because they have extensive gloss that helps to elucidate the text, artscroll has a lot of notes. Sefaria has lots of commentators available on gemmara but usually only in ivrith. I love the Soncino but it can be hard to understand the translation for some because it tends to gloss less. The artscroll gemmara is available as an app with a monthly subscription for $10, which also comes with lots of other artscroll books. you can get it working on your computer if you have windows 11 and patience, otherwise its andriod/ios

Comment: @BID you can also buy a single volume for 10$ one-off - no need for a subscription

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Beur_Reuven_on_Bava_Kamma?tab=contents